How do I set elevation coordinates in adhan-js?
In the adhan-js library, how do I put the coordinates of the height above the ground?
import { Coordinates, CalculationMethod, PrayerTimes } from 'adhan';

const coordinates = new Coordinates(24.71731140399468,  46.55574618993698);
const params = CalculationMethod.UmmAlQura();
const date = new Date();
const prayerTimes = new PrayerTimes(coordinates, date, params);
console.log(prayerTimes);

